# How to use didFinish navigation on an WKWebView passed to another class

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm setting up an app, where the `WKWebView` object is created in one class, and then passed to another class for handling, but when I use `didFinish navigation` in the second class, it never gets called.

I have added the `WKNavigationDelegate` protocol, and set  `navigationDelegate = self`

```
class one: UIViewController {
   var webView: WKWebView = WKWebView();

    override func viewDidLoad(){
      var second = Second()
      second.web = webView;
      second.test()
   } 
}

class second: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
  var web: WKWebView? = nil;

  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
     print("Test")
  }

  func test(){
     self.web!.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))
  }
}
```

I never see the "Test" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it an instance var to retain the object so delegate to be called

```
var second = Second() /// << here

override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()
  ......
}
```

---

```
func test(){ 
   self.web!.navigationDelegate = self
   self.web!.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WKWebViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webWK: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndi: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        webWK.navigationDelegate = self
        let appStoreURL = URL(string: "https://google.com")
        webWK.load(URLRequest(url: appStoreURL!))
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activityIndi.startAnimating()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activityIndi.stopAnimating()
    }

}
```